# I want to fetch latest 3 post from wordpress with title,description ,featured image, date of publish using mysql query or using xmlrpc api

Tags: java, php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display it to jsf site. Currently I am using xmlrpc with jwordpress. I have also access to wordpress db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the title, description and date of publish of latest 3 posts by

```
SELECT post_title, post_content, post_date
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type='post' 
AND post_status='publish' 
ORDER BY post_date 
DESC LIMIT 3;
```

And featured images for the above three posts by

```
SELECT guid 
FROM wp_posts AS a 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT meta_value 
    FROM wpsys_postmeta AS b 
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT ID FROM 
        wpsys_posts 
        WHERE post_type = 'post' 
        AND post_status = 'publish' 
        ORDER BY post_date 
        DESC LIMIT 3 ) AS tbl1 
    ON b.post_id = tbl1.ID and b.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' ) as tbl2 
ON a.ID = tbl2.meta_value;
```

Note:
1) Check your table prefix. Here table prefix is wp_

2) Make sure featured image exists in your latest 3 posts otherwise the second query will result in failure.

Answer (score 0):

write a query in mysql by descending your post uploaded date with limit 3

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY added_date DESC limit 3
```

Comment: it is not what i want

Comment: then tell what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
?>
```

As taken from [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts)